Using selenium to load chrome in pydroid
I am trying to use selenium on pydroid 3. The module and sub modules load, but the browser does not load and gives an error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 67, in _binary_paths
    output = SeleniumManager().binary_paths(self._to_args())             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 45, in binary_paths
    args = [str(self._get_binary())] + args
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 83, in _get_binary
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsupported platform/architecture combination: {sys.platform}/{arch}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsupported platform/architecture combination: linux/aarch64

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 78, in _binary_paths
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

[Program finished]
How to resolve this. Thank you all.
